# The same than / that

Tags: grammaticality

On [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450303/2011), I wrote:

> In particular, g(x) is rational iff f(x) is rational, i.e. g has the same property than f.

My sentence had been corrected to:

> In particular, g(x) is rational iff f(x) is rational, i.e. g has the same property that f.

Can anyone explain to me why the first sentence is not correct, whereas the second one is?

Comment: Neither sentence is correct. Also, please quote the full context, or at least link to the maths.se question, so that we can see for ourselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that is the complete sentence, it would have to be 'The function g has the same property **as** f.'

Answer (score 0):

Barrie's answer is correct. However, it would be better still to identify "the same property" explicitly. If you're only referring to "rational," then the second half of the sentence can be deleted.